# How to pass the array values in HTTP POST method

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have the code like this:

empty values getting passing array object.
when log the details it's showing fine.

**`complaint-reg.component.html`:**

```html
<div class="col-md-6 panel panel-default">
  <h2>Complaint registration</h2>
  <form #complaintRegForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createComplaint(complaintRegForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>District:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="District" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Subject:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Subject" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Place of occurence:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PlaceOfOccurence" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Male" ngModel>Male
      <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Female" ngModel>Female
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Address" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Mobile no:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="MobileNo" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Date of occurence:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DateOfOccurence" ngModel>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**`complaint-reg.component.ts`:**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ComplaintRegistrationService } from './complaint-registration.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-complaint-registartion',
  templateUrl: './complaint-registartion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./complaint-registartion.component.css'],
  providers:[ComplaintRegistrationService]
})
export class ComplaintRegistartionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private complaintCreation : ComplaintRegistrationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  complaintObj = {};
  createComplaint(Obj){
    console.log(Obj);
    this.complaintCreation.createCompliants(Obj).subscribe();
  }

}
```

**and
`complaint-reg.service.ts`:**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()

    export class ComplaintRegistrationService{
        private _url:string ="http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/create"
        constructor(private _http:Http){}
        createCompliants(complaintObj){
            return this._http.post(this._url,complaintObj).map((response:Response)=>console.log(response));
            
        }
    }
```

passing empty values. Attaching screen

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm getting something wrong, but the service logs the response from the server, not the request! What does the service http://192.168.0.106:8000/app/complaint/create return? Did you check the request on the server-side?

Comment: yes it's working fine

Comment: You are logging the response, not the request, so what are you actually receiving in the backend? It seems tho that properties do not match. You have to remember this is case sensitive, so e.g `District` is not the same as `district`

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks.I will try that

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks Bro.it worked a lot

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to point out, that what you are sending and what you are console logging, is NOT the same. Actually what you are logging what the backend is sending you, not what it has received, so your post request is actually probably sending data, it is just in the "wrong format".

Looking at your console, it seems that the problem is that you are sending the properties with upper camel case, but the backend expects you using lower camel case.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind input elements to the `ngModel`. Add binding to input controls like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="District" [(ngModel)]="complaintObj.district" >
```

when you submit the form `complaintObj` should not be empty.